# Is Map<String,AtomicLong> enough to be thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a very simple class:

```
public class IdProvider {

    private Map<String,AtomicLong> idMap;

    public IdProvider(){
        idMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public long getAvailableId(String conversation){
        AtomicLong id = idMap.get(conversation);
        if(id == null){
            id = new AtomicLong(0);
            idMap.put(conversation,id);
        }
        return id.getAndIncrement();
    }


}
```

Different methods asynchronously may pass the same conversation identifier and call `getAvailableId()` where they will be returned a **unique** id.

Is this thread safe? I'm I guaranteed that the no two methods will receive the same id or do I need to opt for something else?

Comment: Definitely not thread safe.  What you're asking about is atomicity, but there's more basic threading issues here too. A mutable object like "idMap" has to be protected by synchronization.

Comment: no NO **NO**. The collection is not threadsafe are therefore **absolutely cannot** be mutated by multiple threads.

Comment: Change `public long getAvailableId(String conversation)` to `public synchronized long getAvailableId(String conversation)`.

Comment: Consider using Guava's `AtomicLongMap`, which takes care of all of this correctly already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple ways to make this thread safe, but below is the simplest, I think.  First, you need to safely publish the initial Map.  Then you need to make each access of that map thread safe.

```
public class IdProvider {

    private final Map<String,AtomicLong> idMap;

    public IdProvider(){
        idMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public synchronized long getAvailableId(String conversation){
        AtomicLong id = idMap.get(conversation);
        if(id == null){
            id = new AtomicLong(0);
            idMap.put(conversation,id);
        }
        return id.getAndIncrement();
    }


}
```

The `final` keyword is one way to provide "safe publication".  (That's an actual term in Java, look it up.)

And without being tricky, just synchronizing the whole method is the easiest way to provide both synchronization and atomicity.  You shouldn't try to do more unless you can profile this code and determine that it is in fact a performance bottle-neck.  Keep It Simple.

Comment: Thank you, can I get rid of the atomic longs and use plain long instead then?

Comment: I think so.  Remember a `Long` in Java is immutable.  You'll have to write the new value back into the Map each time.

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs you can use `Long` and [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to replace almost all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't thread safe.

```
public long getAvailableId(String conversation){
    AtomicLong id = idMap.get(conversation);
    // Thread could be paused here, causing bad interleavings
    // If now a similar call to "getAvailableId" is done you will have two times the same id
    if(id == null){
        id = new AtomicLong(0);
        idMap.put(conversation,id);
    }
    return id.getAndIncrement();
}
```

Make the method synchronized to avoid possible bad interleavings and data races.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to use multiple providers working on same set of ids at the same time,

```
public class IdProvider {

    private static Map<String,Long> idMap;
    static
    {
        idMap = new HashMap<>();
    }
    public Object lock=new Object();

    public IdProvider(Object l){
        lock=l;
    }

    public long getAvailableId(String conversation){
        // do other work
        synchronized(lock)
        {
            Long id = idMap.get(conversation);
            if(id == null){
                id = new Long(0);
                idMap.put(conversation,id);
            }
            return idMap.put(conversation,id+1);
        }

    }
}


Object lock=new Object();

... in a thread:
IdProvider provider=new IdProvider(lock);  // providing from a thread


... in another thread:
IdProvider provider2=new IdProvider(lock); // providing from another
```